# How to localize numbers with DateTimeFormatter?

Tags: java, localization, datetime-format, java-time, localdate

The `java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter` class does not work correctly for locales that use different symbols to represent numbers.

Languages such as Persian (also called Farsi) use different symbols and Unicode characters to represent numbers:
Persian numerals: ۰ ۱ ۲ ۳ ۴ ۵ ۶ ۷ ۸ ۹
Western numerals: 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9

For example:

```java
Locale myLocale = Locale.forLanguageTag("fa");
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy", myLocale);
formatter.format(LocalDate.now()); // should return "۲۰۲۰" but returns "2020"
```

I should say that the `DateFormat` class that is used to format Java legacy `Date`s works as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is fixed in [JDK 15](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/15-relnote-issues.html#JDK-8244245). Use `localizedBy()` (and NOT `localizedWith()`):

```java
formatter
    .localizedBy(myLocale)
    .format(...)
```

For Java versions < 15 format like this:

```java
formatter
    .localizedBy(myLcoale)
    .withDecimalStyle(DecimalStyle.of(myLocale))
    .format(...)
```

Comment: `localizedBy` was actually introduced in [JDK 10](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#localizedBy(java.util.Locale))

Comment: The link was updated. Yes you're right. `LocalizedBy` was introduced in JDK 10 but the fix was implemented in JDK 15 (which may be backported to earlier java versions)